# Python: Generate two mutually-exclusive arrays from one source

Tags: python, arrays, list-comprehension

I have a content source where I split the wheat from the chaff.  I'd like a record of the chaff so it can be visually inspected.  Trouble is, wheat + chaff should equal total content length, but does not. 
 Code below:

```
for report_file in REPORT_FILES:
    with open(report_file, "r+") as filey:
        content_lines = filey.read().split("\n")

    lines = [x for x in content_lines if not any(header in x for header in REPORTS[report_type]["headers"])]    
    trash = [x for x in content_lines if not any(line in x for line in lines)]
```

This code yields {lines} and {trash}, but len(trash) is 0.  I also tried:

```
lines = [x for x in content_lines if not any (header in x for header in REPORTS[report_type]["headers"])]
trash = [x for x in content_lines if any(header in x for header in REPORTS[report_type]["headers"])]
```

but len(lines) + len(trash) is greater than len(content_lines).

Comment: Can you edit the question to include a [mcve]?

Comment: Thank you for your recommendation - I got a proper answer before I got around to typing out an example.

Comment: It would be nice to figure out what caused the problem, though, rather than just work around it. I, for one, am curious!

Comment: I feel you - my recommendation - read in any file with carriage returns that aren't coupled with newline characters.  If I could drop in my data, I would, but it's a heaps of sensitive data, and would take awhile to obfuscate.

Answer (score 1):

For `trash` you can just get all the things in `content_lines` that aren't in `lines`. In code:

```
trash [x for x in content_lines if x not in lines]
```

No need to make it more complicated than this.

**Tip:** You can replace

```
content_lines = filey.read().split("\n")
```

with

```
content_lines = filey.readlines()
```

Answer (score 0):

Answer:  Code-Apprentice's answer, and my second solution in the problem statement were correct.  The validation method was wonked:
when using `wc -l` in bash, it counts the "\n" character, but not "\r".  The report I'm referencing ends some lines with a trailing "\r" not always a "\r\n".